# trigger is not recongnized for MSI protocol withRuby in gem5

Tags: cpu-architecture, gem5

I'm trying to implement MSI protocol in gem5 using Ruby SLICC [version SHA: 8e9b03b640e1c2074896d1123fd55fd336c37d6c] following [this](http://learning.gem5.org/book/part3/MSI/cache-intro.html) source. When I run build, it raises exception and terminates operation.

> Exception: MSI-dir.sm:124: Error: Unrecognized function name: 'trigger_Event_Addr'

Exception occurs at line 219 of [MSI-dir.sm](http://learning.gem5.org/book/_downloads/MSI-dir.sm) file.

```
in_port(memQueue_in, MemoryMsg, responseFromMemory) {
        if (memQueue_in.isReady(clockEdge())) {
            peek(memQueue_in, MemoryMsg) {
                if (in_msg.Type == MemoryRequestType:MEMORY_READ) {
                    trigger(Event:MemData, in_msg.addr); //exception raised here
                } else if (in_msg.Type == MemoryRequestType:MEMORY_WB) {
                    trigger(Event:MemAck, in_msg.addr);
                } else {
                    error("Invalid message");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I cloud not find any detail documentation of trigger function. According to [gem5 documatation](http://www.gem5.org/documentation/general_docs/ruby/slicc/) the number of arguments to trigger depend on the machine itself which I presume means variable arguments.Also my implementation of trigger is valid(I assume) as in `./src/mem/ruby/protocol`  also provides sample protocol file (`Garnet_standalone-dir.sm`) that has trigger implementation with  two argument (`trigger(Event:MemData, in_msg.addr);`) just like mine. My system do not have dma controller.

Why this exception is being raised ? How cloud I solve this issue?

Note: After hours of surfing through internet , it seems like a lot changed in gem5 since [this tutorial](http://learning.gem5.org/book/index.html) was written and it have not been updated. So, any sources on all the changes occurs will be very helpful.
Also, any updated gem5 tutorial sources like this would be nice. Most of the links I found are mainly documents.

Thanks you very much. Piece.

Comment: Also ask on mailing list. Also have a look at the main gem5 code as it already has an MSI implementation that could serve as inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

I just came into the same problem, and can't find any helpful info on the Internet. However, after I reviewed my code, I found that it's maybe because too few arguments I pass in the trigger, like the actions triggered by the event need tbe and/or cache_entry and you didn't pass it to them.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

To add some more information, I think the compiler checks the structures declared within the state machine and looks for a structure with `AbstractCacheEntry` interface with no main='false' and a structure named exactly `TBE`.
When both structures are found, the trigger takes four arguments, namely trigger(Event, Addr, CacheEntry, TBE).

When none of the two structures are found, the trigger takes two arguments trigger(Event, Addr) and you will need to do whatever lookup within your actions.